# Horst Herrlich, Topology I: $T_{3 \frac{1}{2}}$-Reflection and continuous maps.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, separation-axioms

Given the following defintion of a $T_{3 \frac{1}{2}}$ Space:

$\underline{Z}$ is called a $T_{3 \frac{1}{2}}$ Space if for every point $z \in Z$ and every set $A \subset Z$, with $z \not \in A$
there exists a continuous map $m: \underline X \rightarrow \underline{[0,1]}$ with $m(z) = 0$ and $m[A] \subset \{1\}$.

---

In the chapter about $T_{3 \frac{1}{2}}$ Spaces the author defines $\underline Y$ as a s.c. $T_{3 \frac{1}{2}}$-Reflection of a space $\underline X = (X, T_x) $ like this:

$S = \{f^{-1} [B] \ |\ f : \underline X → \underline {[0,1]}  \text{ continuous map }, B \in T_{[0,1]} \}$

$\underline Y = (X, T_y), \text{where} \  T_y$ is a Topology generated by the Subbasis $S$.

If my understanding is right, then he just defines an Initial Topology on a set of all continuous maps from $\underline X$ to $\underline{[0,1]}$ and calls it $\underline Y$.

---

What I don't understand is the following. He proceeds by stating that it is "obvious" that for some $f$ it holds that:

$f: \underline Y \rightarrow \underline{[0,1]}$ is continuous $ \iff $ $f: \underline X \rightarrow \underline{[0,1]}$ is continuous.

While I easily get why the $\Leftarrow$ holds, I just can't understand why $\Rightarrow$ is supposed to hold.

If $f: \underline Y \rightarrow \underline{[0,1]}$ is continuous, then why can't it be that $f: \underline X \rightarrow \underline{[0,1]}$ is a discontinuous map?

Comment: The subbasic open sets of $Y$ are all open in $X$. Thus the topology on $Y$ is weaker than the topology on $X$, and the map induced by the identity $X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous. Now the backwards implication is just the composition of continuous functions.

Comment: @Tyrone Can you elaborate on the last point about the backwards implication?

Comment: Suppose $f:Y\rightarrow [0,1]$ is continuous. Then $X\rightarrow Y\xrightarrow{f}[0,1]$ is continuous because $X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous.

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks. I was lacking the understanding that $T_Y \subset T_X$ because subbasis S would generate the smallest topology containing S. Therefore the identity map would do for the above composition. If you formulate your comment into answer I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity $1_{X,Y}: \underline{X} \to \underline{Y}$ is continuous because the subbase $\mathcal{S}$ is by definition is subfamily of $\mathcal{T}_X$, so that the topology on $\underline{Y}$ is coarser than $\mathcal{T}_X$.

So if $f: \underline{Y} \to [0,1]$ is continuous, the map $f: \underline{X} \to [0,1]$ (same function) can be seen as $f \circ 1_{X,Y}$ and is continuous as a composition of continuous maps.